# Using AVQueuePlayer to get current track information

Tags: iphone, avplayer, avqueueplayer

I am loading my iPod library into AVQueuePlayer and playing it using this:

```
[[AVQueuePlayer alloc]]initWithItems:[MPMediaCollectionInstance items] ];  //just one line.
```

But how do I read which MPMediaItem is currently playing? I want to know information like artist / song name etc. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have the instance of the AVQueuePlayer that you have allocated.

```
AVQueuePlayer *_queuePlayer = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithItems:[MPMediaCollectionInstance items]];
```

With that instance,  you can get the [AVPlayerItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/AVPlayerItem).

```
AVPlayerItem *currentItem = _queuePlayer.currentItem;
```

For the above line, please check the [doc reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVPlayer).

And now try the following code

```
NSArray *metadataList = [currentItem.asset commonMetadata];
for (AVMetadataItem *metaItem in metadataList) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[metaItem commonKey]);
}
```

Which will give a list as follows:

```
title
creationDate
artwork
albumName
artist
```

Now you can get the value for corresponding keys. For this, you have to refer [this doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMetadataItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVMetadataItem) too.

Comment: I only seem to get an empty array for metadataList. When do you call the code to get the metadata? Right after playing the queue?

Comment: Please check whether you have valid `_queuePlayer` and `currentItem` objects. Yes, we need to call that after playing the queue.

Comment: It's still coming empty. I'm running this on an iOS5 device. I tried this right after initializing the queue and calling play. I also tried this in the KVO notification sent to the playerItem that was enqueued ... both cases, commonMetadata returns an empty array.

Comment: Apparently, this works: NSArray *metadataListPlaying = [currentItem.asset metadataForFormat:@"com.apple.itunes"]; this gives an array of 8 keys. Not sure what the difference is, and what kind of formats I should be using if  I'm picking songs from the iPod library.